# QSystemTrayIcon and Windows8

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I writing app and have strange bug in tray class. Inside my class I using `QSystemTrayIcon` like

```
 tray = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
 tray->setIcon(QIcon(":/gui/logo.png"));
 ...
 tray->show();
```

On `WinXP` and `Windows7` it's working properly, but on `Windows 8` icon is not displayed

```
    qDebug()<<"System TRAY:"<< QSystemTrayIcon::isSystemTrayAvailable();// outputs true
```

I use Qt5.1.1 MSVC 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just had the same problem, the solution i used from phyatt is to copy the **imageformats** folder to **plugins** folder of my apps, and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not the system tray icon loads, I have found is more dependent on if it can load the file type.

Is the appropriate plugin available in your deployment environment?

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/43152-Deploying-Qt-Application-on-Windows-Load-JPG-Images-Problem

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html

Hope that helps.

UPDATE: Qt 5.1 w/ msvc 2012 32bit test results of `QSystemTrayIcon` on Windows 8 Pro:
Compiling and building the test application with the following in a stock UI Form project,
with the following in the mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QSystemTrayIcon * sys = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
//    sys->setIcon(QIcon("C:/Users/phyatt/Downloads/system-tray.png"));
    sys->setIcon(QIcon(":/gui/system-tray.png"));
    sys->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

And with these dependencies next to the exe, it runs just fine.

[image: Qt 5.1 dependencies]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I uses png icon, and tray not only is not displayed and did not appear at all

Comment: I tried to recreate your error in Windows 8, Qt 4.8.4, and there was no error for me.

Comment: I Use Qt5.1.1 MSVC 2012

Comment: Have you tried the Qt SysTray Example?  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/desktop-systray.html  It should be included with the Qt Libraries.  Or you can launch it from the demo program.

Comment: I think it is Qt5 bug.

Comment: So it looks like the SysTray demo isn't included in Qt5 yet... but I just tried your test case in Windows 8, Qt 5.1.1, MSVC 2012 32 bit, and it works just fine.