# QSystemTrayIcon shows only place holder and not the real icon

Tags: c++, qt

My code below brings up the icon but its like empty with nothing in it. if I move the mouse cursor over the expected icon location (last one) in system tray, its there but it doesn't show the real icon. It's more like just a place holder for the icon.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    systemTray = new QSystemTrayIcon();

    systemTray->setIcon( QIcon::fromTheme("edit-undo") ); // stock icon but I have tried use local icon file too with same result

    systemTray->setVisible( true ); // extra insurance
    systemTray->show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using Qt 5.4 and Windows 7

Comment: Your version of Qt, desktop environment, operating system?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy just updated post, 5.4

Comment: Have you tried the system icons example?

Comment: Look for it here: `C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.4\widgets\desktop\systray`  They stopped listing it online and in their examples listing in the Welcome tab for some reason.

Comment: For icons and images, adding the images as a qt resource file and referencing the url that way tends to be very robust.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18707530/999943

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the stock icon doesn't work but it was a syntax and qmake issue. I had the path given as `":/icons/file.ico"` or `"icons/file.ico"`. The correct syntax is below otherwise it will not show the actual icon. Also I had to 'run qmake' apparently needed when new icon is added to qrc because even when the syntax was right, the problem was still there.

```
systemTray->setIcon( QIcon(":icons/file.ico") );
```