# QSystemTrayIcon not showing after using windeployqt tool

Tags: c++, windows, qt

**Note: Yes, this question has been asked and answered previously, but the duplicate's answer is incomplete. Please see my solution if you are stuck on this.**

Using Qt 5.13.0 MSVC2017 64-bit and Windows 10, I'm experiencing some strange behavior from QSystemTrayIcon. When running in Debug or Release from QtCreator on a fresh build, there are no issues and the icon displays exactly how I would expect it to. However, after using the `windeployqt.exe` tool, the icon stops showing up.

This happens both when I run it from QtCreator after `windeployqt.exe` and from the installation directory via Qt Installer Framework. If I delete the build directory, clean, and rebuild, the problem goes away, but obviously this is an issue for deployment.

Command:

```
windeployqt.exe <RELEASE_DIR>
```

(also tried specifying the executable directly)

MainWindow constructor:

```cpp
AltheaWindow::AltheaWindow(MacroListModel &macroListModel, Config *config, const QString &configPath, QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent),
          ui(new Ui::AltheaWindow),
          macros(macroListModel),
          config(config),
          trayIcon(QIcon(IconPath), this),
          shortcutNew(ShortcutPtr(new QShortcut(NewMacro, this))),
          shortcutSave(ShortcutPtr(new QShortcut(SaveMacro, this))) {
    qDebug() << "AltheaWindow";
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->sidebar->createSettingsDialog(config, configPath);
    initConnections();
    QFile f(IconPath);
    bool exists = f.exists();
    qDebug() << "exists = " << exists; // "exists = true"
    trayIcon.show();
    ui->sidebar->setMacros(&macroListModel);
    if ((*(*config)[AltheaConfig::StartMinimized]).toBool()) showMinimized();
}
```

Regardless of whether the icon is shown or not, `exists` is always `true`, so it doesn't seem to be an issue of resolving the resource. All other resources in the application work fine as well.

Comment: How `IconPath` looks like? And sometimes, the tray icon is hidden - you must explicitly show it on the task bar using Windows settings.

Comment: `const QString AltheaWindow::IconPath = ":/icons/althea.ico";`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by explicitly showing it in Windows settings?

Comment: On the right side of the task bar, where you expect to see tray icons, there is a small arrow-button `^`. It's tool tip says "Show hidden icons". When you click it, a pop up appears with some additional icons. Is your icon among them?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, all icons are hidden for me by default, no it is not in there. It is there before I use windeployqt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, copy imageformats to the plugins directory.

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20594583/2472874

Additional note:
For anyone experiencing this issue, I found that I also needed to have the imageformats plugin on the Library Paths *before* the application object is initialized.

```cpp
#define PLUGINS "plugins"

void preInit(char *argv[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
#ifndef _DEBUG
    preInit(argv);
#endif
    Althea app(argc, argv);
    AltheaWindow w(app.getMacros(), &app.getConfig(), app.getAppData().absoluteFilePath(Althea::ConfigFileName));
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}

void preInit(char *argv[]) {
    QDir releaseDir(QFileInfo(argv[0]).dir());
    QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath(releaseDir.absoluteFilePath(PLUGINS));
}
```